# expected } for some reason

Tags: c#

The following code is giving me these errors,

} expected

Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Derpy merp = new Derpy();
            merp.OnDerp += new EventHandler(herp);
            void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

        }


    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe `void herp` defined in the middle of `button1_Click` should stand out to you.

Comment: void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }    <- delete that   , I'm guessing you tried to write private before void , but VS wouldn't let you fro a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

You can't embed a named function inside of another function like this.

Comment: Yes, you can, you just can't name it and you must store it in a delegate variable or use it in some other fashion (like attaching it to an event handler).

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1**:
try this (Anonymous Method):

```
merp.OnDerp += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // add your code here...
        // may be 
        // derpy = ((Derpy) sender);
        // be useful.
    };
```

---

**Solution 2**:
And simplest way:

```
 // add event handler
 merp.OnDerp += new EventHandler(herp);
```

and use it:

```
// this must be in class body. not in another method
void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add your code here...
}
```

---

see these lessons:

- [Introduction to Delegates and Events](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson14)
- [How Do Anonymous Methods Benefit Me?](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson21)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error because you are trying to declare an ordinary named function inside another function, but C# only supports *anonymous* functions declared within other functions.

To use an anonymous function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Derpy merp = new Derpy();
  merp.OnDerp += (sender, e) =>    
  {

  };
}
```

Or bring your method outside the click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Derpy merp = new Derpy();
  merp.OnDerp += new EventHandler(herp);
}
void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Your first sentence says that you cannot declare a function inside of another, then you proceed to do that (correctly) by declaring an *anonymous* function. I would suggest rewording your first sentence to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks @AdamRobinson, please don not hesitate to edit my answer, any correction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the right will be

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Derpy merp = new Derpy();
            merp.OnDerp += new EventHandler(herp);


        }
        private void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code

```
void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

maybe better off being a method itself.  I don't think C# supports method within method like JavaScript

Comment: You can declare an *anonymous method* within the body of another method. You just can't name it as he's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Nested methods found in your code, and **C#** does not support it.

**USE:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Derpy merp = new Derpy();
     merp.OnDerp += new EventHandler(herp);

}

void herp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```